# Oracle SQL ternary operator or function?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, conditional-operator, oracle19c

Is there a simple Oracle syntax like a ternary operator or function?

These work:

```sql
with
function qry(v in varchar2) return varchar2 is
   begin
      return owa_util.ite(v like ('%' || lower('something') || '%'),'Y','N');
   end;
select * from my_table where qry(my_col) = 'Y'
```

```sql
with
function qry(v in varchar2) return varchar2 is
   begin
      return case when v like('%' || lower('something') || '%') then 'Y' else 'N' end;
   end;
select * from my_table where qry(my_col) = 'Y'
```

If there's a simpler, shorter syntax I would like to know.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would help.  Why would you want a function, when `like` is much simpler?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly like in the code, check if string match and return `Y` or `N`. I would like something shorter than `if X then return A else return B end if`.

Comment: You can use a `case` expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression with `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  CASE WHEN my_col LIKE '%something%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END = 'Y';
```

or `DECODE` and `INSTR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  DECODE( INSTR( my_col, 'something' ), 0, 'N', 'Y' ) = 'Y';
```

or just simply use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  my_col LIKE '%something%';
```

`INSTR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  INSTR( my_col, 'something' ) > 0;
```

or `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( my_col, 'something' );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0adaa9da8c026f310330ca5a8814bf9d)*

Comment: Ok, but I would like to have it in a function because the code will be reused in many places, so I can't use `DECODE`.

Comment: @user5507535 You really do not need a function; just use `LIKE` as per the 3rd example. If you wrap it in a function then Oracle will not use any indexes that you have on the column.